# ASP.NET - API 400 error on GET request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have this Controller:

```
namespace Cantrel.Application.CantrelSearchApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [Authorize]
    public class MonitorsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IMonitoringApiService monitoringService;
        private readonly IClientsApiService clientsService;
        private readonly ILogger<MonitorsController> logger;

        public MonitorsController(IMonitoringApiService monitoringService,
            IClientsApiService clientsService,
            ILogger<MonitorsController> logger)
        {
            this.monitoringService = monitoringService;
            this.clientsService = clientsService;
            this.logger = logger;
        }

  [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string id)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(null))
        {
            return BadRequest("No id was provided. Please provide a valid monitor id or subject id.");
        }

        try
        {
            MonitorDto monitor;

            if (Guid.TryParse(id, out Guid monitorId))
            {
                monitor = await GetByMonitorId(monitorId);
            }
            else
            {
                monitor = await GetBySubjectId(id);
            }

            if (monitor == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Json(monitor);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.LogError($"[{Request.Path.Value}]: {ex.ToString()}");
            return new StatusCodeResult(500);
        }
    }
```

I make the following call in Postman:

```
GET: {{api}}/Monitors/ABCDEFGH-1234-4567-8901-ABCDEFGHIJKL
```

Instead of the expected return of information on that monitor I receive a `400 Bad Request` error with the message `No id was provided. Please provide a valid monitor id or subject id`.

I'm not sure I understand how this is happening.  The string is clearly neither NULL or empty.

Please let me know if there is any other classes' code I should provide to assist in diagnosis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is always true:

```
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(null)) //always true!
        {
            return BadRequest("No id was provided. Please provide a valid monitor id or subject id.");
        }
```

Thus you will always get a BadRequest response. You will need to change it to:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
```

Comment: Wow, how incredibly obvious and insane of me to miss!  @JanR thank you so much for providing a helpful answer that helps me instead of downvoting my post and voting to close it!

Comment: Of course now I'm getting a 500 Internal Server error instead, but I'll save that for another thread!

Comment: Downvoters and close-voters - https://stackoverflow.com/conduct . This is not a judgement zone for people making silly mistakes.  I'll admit this was a very glaring oversight on my part.  I thank @JanR for helping me instead of downvoting.

Comment: we've all been there, no judgement needed :)

Comment: Thanks @JanR - I sometimes hesitate to even post here b/c of it.  People like you and many other helpful folks here make it well-worth it though.